# allocate array of objects using void pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic, void, allocation

i am trying to allocate array of different datatype, decided on runtime. Consider the following, Please excuse for formatting:

```
#include <iostream>

unsigned int Wlines;

class Cache_X_line          //Datatype1
{   public:
    unsigned int Tag;
};

class Cache_Y_line         //Datatype2
{   public:
    unsigned int lob;
};

class Cache_set
{   private:
    unsigned int i;

    public:
    void **line;                                //Using void pointer

    Cache_set(bool linetype)
    {   if(Wlines!=0)
            line= new void * [Wlines];          //array of void pointers

        for(i=0;i<Wlines;i++)
        {   if(linetype)
                line[i]=new Cache_X_line;       //allocating objects of datatype1 

            else
                line[i]=new Cache_Y_line;       //allocating objects of datatype2
        }
    }
};

int main()

{   cout<<"Enter Wlines:";
    cin>>Wlines;

    Cache_set Set(1);               //Object having member that is allocated array of datatype1.

    clog<<hex<<Set.((Cache_X_line *)line[i])->Tag;  //PROBLEM: UNABLE TO TYPECAST, to access members of allocated object.

}
```

I am able to allocate array of objects of datatype1/datatype2, datatype decided at runtime. But i don't know how to access member of each object further. Please help.

Comment: You shouldn't do this using `void*` pointers, use interfaces and `dynamic_cast<>` instead.

Comment: `i am trying to allocate array of different datatype, decided on runtime`  Tell us what you *really* want to do on a high-level, not your "solution" that you're trying to get to work.

Answer (score 3):

> I am able to allocate array of objects of datatype1/datatype2, datatype decided at runtime. But i don't know how to access member of each object further.

My suggestion:

1. Create a common base class from which `Cache_X_Line`, and `Cache_Y_Line` can derive. Make sure the base class has at least one virtual function. In nothing else can be made virtual, make the destructor virtual.
2. Store pointers to the base class instead of `void*` in `Cache_Set`. It will be better to store a `std::vector` of smart pointers instead of storing raw pointers.
3. When using the pointers, do a `dynamic_cast`. When a `dynamic_cast` succeeds to a derived type, used the derived type.